# Is it possible to populate a user field in the CP using custom logic upon registration?

Tags: craft3, users

Whenever a user is registered in the control panel, we'd like to have a special field (something like a special member id) that is populated either by manual entry or, if the field is left empty, run custom logic to generate a new value for that field.

Is this possible using Craft's events or by extending the existing user registration form available in the CP, or would it be easier to create a separate plug-in to handle the user creation process?

Answer (score 1):

The Preparse plugin may help you accomplish what you want. https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft